# graphql where filter - "Unknown argument \"where\"

Tags: filter, graphql, arguments, where-clause

I tried to use where: filter on graphql query but unfortunately I got some error. What am I doing wrong?

```
shoeposts {
  data {
    attributes(where: {slug: "NikeDunkLow"}) 
    {
      title
      slug
    }
  }
}}
```

````
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Unknown argument \"where\" on field \"ShoepostEntity.attributes\".",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 4,
            "column": 18
          }
        ],
        "extensions": {
          "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
          "exception": {
            "stacktrace": [
              "GraphQLError: Unknown argument \"where\" on field ```

Thanks in advance
````

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using Strapi

you should use filters instead where. And you should inform the conditional

```
and, or, not, eq, qei, ne, startsWith, endsWith, contains, notContains, containsi, notContainsi, gt, gte, lt, lte, null, notNull,in, notIn, between

shoeposts {
  data {
    attributes(filters: {slug: { eq: "NikeDunkLow" }}) 
    {
      title
      slug
    }
  }
}}
```